# Proper mysql sorting practices

Tags: mysql, sorting

this TYPE of question has been asked before but not to my situation. 
I am wondering what the proper sorting technique would be for my situation.

lets say we have 10 users that store data for everyday of the week in a mysql database.

we have an index field that is autoincrement but we also store the username as well.

is it better to sort the mysql database by username and then date after each entry and then when we do a DB search just output the array as is

OR

is it better to do a DB search, sort the array and then output it?

Comment: Always use `order by` in a query if you want the results in a particular order.

Answer (score 1):

The order of rows is not guaranteed so it is pointless to try to order the rows in a database. Have your query get sorted instead of the database.

This is not specific to MySQL.

See this answer:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql/6061#6061

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to search a lot on a given set of fields, in other words, if you end up with many commands such as (or one command repeated many times):

```
SELECT <some fields> FROM <table> WHERE a = <some value> AND b = <some value>
```

Then it is a good idea to add an index with a and b. The syntax varies depending on the database system you use, but generally, something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX <some name> ON <table> (a, b);
```

The order of a and b should not matter much in an index. Although from what you are saying, each user will have a list of dates, not the other way around, so probably the user first.

Then the SQL system will automatically pick up the index when handling a WHERE that include 'a' and 'b'.

Note that in the most advanced SQL engines (I know PostgreSQL does it, MySQL most certainly too) such indexes may automatically be generated by the SQL manager. The manager gathers statistics that can be used to auto generate indexes. However, those are not as reliable as the ones you create explicitly.